# how to retrieve multiple columns data from a table in html response in android

Tags: android

Hi Guys i am new to android applications,i had made the web request using the POST method and 
got the html respone page displayed in logcat.The html response page is containing the table from which i need to retrieve 1,4,5,7 columns of data and store each column data in an array. 
Below is the html source code for the table data. Please some one provide me the sample code so 
that i can retrieve the columns data and display in a list. Thanks for any response related to 
this is appreciated.

```
< html>< head>
    < meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
< /head>
< body>
< center>
    <tr>
          <td height="141"><table width="980" border="1" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="1">
          <tr>
            <td height="23" bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column1</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2"  color="#FFFFFF">Column2</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column3</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column4</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column5</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column6</font></strong></td>
            <td bgcolor="#2C66A7"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#FFFFFF">Column7</font></strong></td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
                <td height="29">&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >Data1</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >10-Aug-09</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >17:50</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>
              </tr>
              ...............................
              ...............................
              ...............................
              ...............................
              <tr>
                <td height="29">&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >Data6</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>                  
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >13-Aug-09</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >15:39</font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" ></font></td>
                <td>&nbsp;<font face="Arial" size="2" >column7data</font></td>
              </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr> 
 < /center>< /body> < /html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should parse this document with a XML parser - you can choose from DOM parser, SAX parser and others. A nice tutorial for working with XML parser is available here: [Working with XML in Android](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-android/)

Here is an example of function parsing XML file from URL using DOM:

```
    public static Document parseDOMfromURL(String url_str)
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(url_str);
            InputSource input = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(input);

            return doc;
        } 

        catch (MalformedURLException e) { ErrorMSG("Bad URL: " + url_str);  } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { ErrorMSG("Unsupported encoding");  } 
        catch (IOException e) { ErrorMSG("Failed to parse Document from input stream"); e.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) { ErrorMSG("Failed to init document builder"); } 
        catch (SAXException e) { ErrorMSG("Failed to parse Document from input stream (SAX)");}

        return null;
    }
```

When you obtain `Document`, in your case, you can call `document.findElementsByTagName("tr")`; After that, cycle through every NodeArray and process the `td` elements:

```
        NodeList tr_tags = doc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (int i=0; i<tr_tags.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node tr_tag = tr_tags.item(i);
            for (Node node=tr_tag.getFirstChild(); node!=null; node=node.getNextSibling())
            {
                if (node.getNodeName().equals("td"))
                {
                    // DO YOUR WORK HERE
                }
            }
        }
```